# Write random Python data to CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a small python script that uses a library to generate random dates(mm/dd/yyyy) and random time based on a 12 hour clock..

```
def randomPhone():
    n ='0000000000'
    while '0' in n[3:6] or n[3:6]=='000':
    n = str(random.randint(10**9, 10**10-1))
    return n[:3] + '-' + n[3:6] + '-' + n[6:]
    randomPhone ()

def strTimeProp(start, end, format, prop):
    stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, format))
    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)
    return time.strftime(format, time.localtime(ptime))

def randomDate(start, end, prop):
    return strTimeProp(start, end, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', prop)

print randomDate("1/1/2016 12:00 AM", "1/1/2017 12:00 AM", random.random())
```

I have code to generate other random data, like names, and phone numbers. But first I want to write the date and time to a CSV file and make sure the formatting is correct. So the date and time are correctly displayed in a nicely formatted table, however when I try to add in the `phoneNumber()` argument I run into problems. The table displays when only the Date/Time argument is passed, and how I want it to looks, but with another section added onto the end for a Phone#, etc.

[image]

```
f = open("CDR.csv", 'wt')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ('Date/Time', 'Phone#') )
    for i in range(1):
        writer.writerow( (randomDate("1/1/2016 12:00 AM", "1/1/2017 12:00 AM", random.random())), randomPhone() )
finally:
    f.close()

print open("CDR.csv", 'rt').read()
```

However I'm getting a typeError, `writerow() takes exactly one argument and two are given'

I'm following [CSV Writing](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/) as an example.

Comment: that's because you're passing 2 arguments to `writerow` :)

Comment: Try to generate a `random_row` first, print it to make sure you understand what you've generated, then `.writerow(random_row)` with confidence.

Comment: or make sure all your funcs return strings and then concatenate them before feeding into `writerow()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your parentheses in the wrong place, causing you to pass two arguments to `.writerow()` instead of a single tuple.

Try separating your tuple creation from the function call. This should make the code easier to read.

```
row = (
    randomDate("1/1/2016 12:00 AM", "1/1/2017 12:00 AM", random.random()), 
    randomPhone(),
)
writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Perfect, the example I was following threw me off. Thank you.

Comment: Note that I've changed my advice. I think this version is more readable than what I suggested previously.